# Parsley: Custom Validator Scope

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

Is there a way of attaching custom Parsley validators to one form instance only? The only thing I've found is `ParsleyValidator.addValidator()`, but that makes them globally available (which in turn makes removing them via `ParsleyValidator.removeValidator()` more tricky when multiple forms are involved). I need to remove them once they are no longer used in order to avoid memory leaks (the application is running 24/7 so reloading the page is not an option). Apparently there is no such thing as `ParsleyForm.addValidator()`. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such way currently, and there is no plan for such a way in the future unless someone convinces us of the need.

Because it should not be needed. You have to distinguish a *validator*, which is the code that decides if a value is acceptable or not, i.e. the algorithm used, from the *requirements* themselves (bounds or other parameters) which should be specified via the input's parameters or options.

The validator is registered globally, but the requirements are local to the inputs.

`Parsley` has a correspondence between data attributes & javascript, so you might simply need to use the javascript API. E.g, you can add a requirement simply by doing

```
$('.my-input').parsley().options.excludevalues = ['not this', 'nor this']
```

I'm basically done rewriting the code of the validators (see the `promise` branch), which introduces a new API. Among other things, it's easy to define a custom validator with more complex parameters, and the field instance is also passed as a parameter when validation.

If you actually have a case where you actually need "local" custom validators, please provide more details about your case...

Comment: Is there another way to pass requirements to the validator function other than serializing them into some data attribute or referencing them directly in the validator function? Example use case: A name must be unique within a given set.